# jQuery Autocomplete with Focusout solution

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, focusout

I want to autofill the input field when user insert right value and escape the input field. An example of this is https://www.redbus.in/
I am using url string to send data request, and after that receive the result. I want to keep sending the data request and receiving results even the user excape the field? Then first value of the list with results must be selected. THAN YOU FOR THE HELP !

My code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( "#econt_offices_town" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        autoFocus: true,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    action:'handle_ajax', 
                    city: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response(jQuery.map(data, function(item) {
                                    return {
                                        label:      item.label,
                                        value:      item.value,
                                        city_id:    item.id,
                                        post_code:   item.post_code           
                                    };
                            }));
                }, //end of success
            }); //end of ajax
        }, //end of source
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var city_id = ui.item.city_id;
            var post_code = ui.item.post_code;
            jQuery('#econt_offices_postcode').val(post_code);
            jQuery('#office_locator').show(); //show office locator button after the city is selected
            jQuery('#econt_offices_postcode, label[for="econt_offices_postcode"], #econt_offices, label[for="econt_offices"]').show();
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    action:'handle_ajax', 
                    office_city_id: city_id, 
                    delivery_type: 'to_office'
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    jQuery('#econt_offices').empty()
                    jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        jQuery('#econt_offices').append(jQuery("<option/>", {
                                value: value.id,
                                text: value.value + ' [о.к.:' + value.id + ']'
                        }));
                    });
                    calculate_loading(); //calculate loading cost for shipping to office
                } //end of success
            }); //end of ajax
        }, //end of select
    }); //end of #econt_offices_town .autocomplete
```

Comment: Just a side note but this looks like a good case for a class: `jQuery('#econt_offices_postcode, label[for="econt_offices_postcode"], #econt_offices, label[for="econt_offices"]').show();` such as `jQuery('.postcodethings').show();`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the some additional event management with some creative use.

If I understand you want to select a value when someone tabs out OR clicks somewhere else (focus lost)

```
$("#econt_offices_town").on('keydown focusout', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode != $.ui.keyCode.TAB && !(event.type == "focusout")) return;

  event.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.DOWN;
  event.type = "keydown";//change the event from focusout
  $(this).trigger(event);

  event.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
  $(this).trigger(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. THis is how to autoselect if only one value in the list. I put this code between "source" and "Select"

```
response: function(event,ui) {
            if (ui.content.length == 1) {
                ui.item = ui.content[0];
                jQuery( "#econt_offices_town" ).data('ui-autocomplete')._trigger('select', 'autocompleteselect', ui);
                jQuery( "#econt_offices_town" ).autocomplete('close');
            }
        },
```